# How to validate the response of a JSON attribute when key is number in Karate?

Tags: karate

- def payload = {"1":{"clientName":"Peter Thomas"}, "2":{"clientName": "Karate Framework"}}

I need to find the path of clientName attribute and validate the values of it.

I tried * match payload.1.clientName == 'Peter Thomas', but it is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me fine on Karate 1.0.1

```
* def payload = {"1":{"clientName":"Peter Thomas"}, "2":{"clientName": "Karate Framework"}}
* match payload.1.clientName == 'Peter Thomas'
```

Maybe you are on an old version. Please upgrade. The below may work for you - note that the `"1"` in the original payload is a string:

```
* match payload['1'].clientName == 'Peter Thomas'
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. It is working perfectly. Marked the answer as accepted. But while using print keyword, it is throwing an error.

>>> failed features:
>>>> js failed.
01: karate.log([print], payload.1.clientName)

Comment: @Nasruddin open a new question if needed. note that this is an open source project, why don't you help us fix this "throwing an error" that you refer to